# salt encryption from C# to Swift 3

Tags: c#, swift, encryption, salt

I have written the following code in swift to try and replicate something I have working in C#. I know I have gone wrong but I'm not exactly sure where.
The code is meant to encrypt a string and return an encrypted string. The encrypted string should remain the same every time. Unfortunately the webservice that this app connects to is a bit old and I have no control to change it.
Thank you for any assistance!

Swift code:

```
enum HMACAlgorithm {
    case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512

    func toCCHmacAlgorithm() -> CCHmacAlgorithm {
        var result: Int = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
        case .SHA1:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
        case .SHA224:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
        case .SHA256:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
        case .SHA384:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
        case .SHA512:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
        }
        return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
    }

    func digestLength() -> Int {
        var result: CInt = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA1:
            result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA224:
            result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA256:
            result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA384:
            result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA512:
            result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
        }
        return Int(result)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Encypt Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var stringToEn: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outputEn: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func encyptPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let input = stringToEn.text
        let hmacResult: String = input!.hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm.SHA1, key: "GVDev789")
        outputEn.text = hmacResult


    }

}
extension String{

    func hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {
        let cKey = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let cData = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        var result = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(algorithm.digestLength()))
        CCHmac(algorithm.toCCHmacAlgorithm(), cKey!, 1000, cData!, 1000, &result)
//        cchmac Int(strlen(cKey!))  Int(strlen(cData!))
        let hmacData:NSData = NSData(bytes: result, length: (Int(algorithm.digestLength())))
        let hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength76Characters)
        return String(hmacBase64)
    }
}
```

What is working in C#

```
public static string getEncryptedText(string input)
        {
            return EncryptText(input);
        }

 private static string EncryptText(string strText)
        {
            PasswordDeriveBytes pdbPassword = default(PasswordDeriveBytes);
            PasswordDeriveBytes pdbIV = default(PasswordDeriveBytes);
            DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] salt = {
                        (byte)Strings.Asc("G"),
                        (byte)Strings.Asc("V"),
                        (byte)Strings.Asc("D"),
                        (byte)Strings.Asc("e"),
                        (byte)Strings.Asc("v"),
                        (byte)Strings.Asc("7"),
                        (byte)Strings.Asc("8"),
                        (byte)Strings.Asc("9")
            };
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cs = default(CryptoStream);
            string plainText = strText;
            byte[] plainBytes = null;
            plainBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            pdbPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes("Password", salt);
            pdbPassword.HashName = "SHA1";
            pdbPassword.IterationCount = 1000;
            DES.Key = pdbPassword.GetBytes(8);

            pdbIV = new PasswordDeriveBytes("PbeIv", salt);
            pdbIV.HashName = "SHA1";
            pdbIV.IterationCount = 1000;
            DES.IV = pdbIV.GetBytes(8);
            cs = new CryptoStream(ms, DES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Comment: For example code see: [MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512 (Swift 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/7885/cryptographic-hashing/25614/md2-md4-md5-sha1-sha224-sha256-sha384-sha512-swift-3#t=201705301850586282815).

Comment: You need to provide sample data from each and a [mcve]. Note: the question will most likely be closed soon without this. Also hashing is not encryption.

Comment: thanks Zaph will check out the link, not sure why you think the question will be closed. I provided the code in c# which 100% works.

Also interesting that this is not encryption, I never realised there was a difference between hashing and encryption!

Comment: Hashing uniquely identifies, and obscures the original data and does not allow it's retrieval.  Encryption allows the original data to be retrieved given the encryption key.  Where "uniquely" is sufficiently broadly defined :)

Comment: thanks David that makes sense!